# Capturing Sequel::Error exceptions

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I have a Sinatra app utilizing Sequel and Postgres... it's a very simple module that inserts into a database.  I want to capture any errors from the insert and return a useful message.

My codes is as follows:

```
begin
   sql = DB["INSERT INTO table (id, firstname, lastname, ...) values (......)"]
   ds.insert
rescue Sequel::Error
   ...
end
```

How do I capture what the actual error is?  I can put "There was an error" and that is printed, but I want something more specific - like "First name is required", "Last name is required".

Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the last exception object magic constant `$!`:

```
rescue Sequel::Error
  p $!.message
end
```

Also you can change the rescue block to put the exception object into a variable:

```
rescue Sequel::Error => e
  p e.message
end
```

Both would print the exception messsage.

Comment: Thanks.  Figured this would be an easy one.